# YouTube issue across browsers on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, youtube

On YouTube only, on both Firefox and Chromium for 18.04, all videos look like the image shown below with the bottom and right section of the video underlapping the page elements. This means I can't even watch in fullscreen as the icon is "under the page". This is occurring in the latest versions of both Firefox and Chromium, and all software is otherwise up-to-date.

[image: youtube error]
<sup>**YouTube error**</sup>

Comment: And you can use "F" for full screen (ESC to get back to normal view).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'll bear that in mind, though it would be nice to have the problem remedied.

Comment: Do you have your page zoomed in on YouTube? Even if you do not, try to Ctrl - and see if that works.
EDIT - Also, what is your screen resolution? It might effect this too.

Comment: @Syd aye that's got it. Apparently I was zoomed in Thanks. Can't quite explain why it does it on Chromium though, which I never use and therefore never zoom in on. Sorted. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was the only one with this problem.

Anyway, the quickfix is resizing the window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> if opening a docked console works too!),

the little longer fix is writing a browser extension that automatically does

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
```

everytime a youtube link loads.

and the best fix is begging google and firefox on bugzilla for a fix in emails for a fix

I'm not entirely sure if this is a stupid move on googles part for not testing it on ubuntu, or this is a ubuntu thing, either way lets hope this goes away !

Answer (score 0):

1. Install "Synaptic Manager"
2. Search for adobe
3. Install "adobe-flashplugin"